# Scraping web with java and downloading a video

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scraping this 9gag [link](https://9gag.com/gag/a2ZG6Yd)

I tried using JSoup to get this HTML [tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bdxe.png)
for taking the source link and download the video directly.

I tried with this code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Response response= Jsoup.connect("https://9gag.com/gag/a2ZG6Yd")
                   .ignoreContentType(true)
                   .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")  
                   .referrer("https://www.facebook.com/")
                   .timeout(12000) 
                   .followRedirects(true)
                   .execute();

        Document doc = response.parse();
        System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTag("video"));
    }
```

but I get nothing

I tried then this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Response response= Jsoup.connect("https://9gag.com/gag/a2ZG6Yd")
                   .ignoreContentType(true)
                   .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")  
                   .referrer("https://www.facebook.com/")
                   .timeout(12000) 
                   .followRedirects(true)
                   .execute();

        Document doc = response.parse();
        System.out.println(doc.getAllElements());
    }
```

and I noticed that in the HTML there is not the tag I'm looking for, as if the page is loaded dynamically and the tag "video" is not loaded yet

What could I do?
Thank you all

Comment: You'll need to do whatever a browser would do to trigger the sending of the video tag.  No easy task since it's probably Javascript.

Comment: Can't I just tell to JSoup to trigger all the javascript event when landing on the page?

Comment: Probably, but do you know what triggers the sending of the tag?  It could be scrolling the page down or clicking on a button, or something else.

Comment: In teory just landing on the page i can see the tag, without scrolling or clicking anything

Comment: It could well be loading the tag as part of an ajax request once the main page has loaded.  I'd use the web developer tools to find out what the request is that gets the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's reverse the approach. You already know we're looking for URL like `https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a2ZG6Yd_460svvp9.webm`
(To obtain URL of the video you could also right click it in Chrome and select "Copy video address").

If you search page source you will find `a2ZG6Yd_460svvp9.webm` but it's stored in JSON inside `<script>`.

[image]

That's not a good news for Jsoup because it can't be parsed, but we can use simple regular expression to get this link. The URL is escaped so we have to remove backslashes. Then you can use Jsoup to download the file.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://9gag.com/gag/a2ZG6Yd").ignoreContentType(true)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                .referrer("https://www.facebook.com/").timeout(12000).followRedirects(true).get();

        String html = doc.toString();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"vp9Url\":\"([^\"]+?)\"");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
        if (m.find()) {
            String escpaedURL = m.group(1);
            String correctUrl = escpaedURL.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
            System.out.println(correctUrl);
            downloadFile(correctUrl);
        }
    }

    private static void downloadFile(String url) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out = (new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\file.webm")));
        out.write(Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).execute().bodyAsBytes());
        out.close();
    }
```

Also note that `vp9Url` is not the only one there, so maybe the other one will be more suitable, for example `h265Url` or `webpUrl`.